# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, .net-4.5

I am working with .NET4.5 and VS2013, I have this query that gets `dynamic` result from db.

```
dynamic topAgents = this._dataContext.Sql(
    "select t.create_user_id as \"User\", sum(t.netamount) as \"Amount\" from transactiondetail t where t.update_date > sysdate -7 group by t.create_user_id")
    .QueryMany<dynamic>();
```

Following statement fails with compilation error `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`
without even allowing me to run it

```
topAgents.ToList().Select(agent => new
{
    User = agent.User != null ? string.Format("{0}", agent.User).Replace("CORPNTGB\\", "") : null,
    Amount = agent.Amount
});
```

while this one with `foreach` works just fine.

```
var data = new List<List<object>>();
foreach (dynamic agent in topAgents)
{
    data.Add(new List<object>
    {
        agent.User != null ? string.Format("{0}", agent.User).Replace("CORPNTGB\\", "") : null,
        agent.Amount
    });
}
```

In my eyes after I `topAgents.ToList()` they could be interpreted as equivalent, is it because I explicitly state that `var data = new List<List<object>>();` that second statement is allowed by compiler?

**Why doesn't compiler allow LINQ select, but allows for each`?**

Comment: Does `topAgents` have to be `dynamic`? Does it work if you use `var` instead?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The problem is that `topAgents` is `dynamic` - so your `ToList()` call is dynamic, and so is `Select`. That has issues that:

1. you can't use lambda expressions for dynamic calls like this;
2. dynamic calls don't find extension methods anyway.

Fortunately, the operations don't need to be dynamic just because the *element* type is dynamic. You could use:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> topAgents = ...;
```

... or just use `var`. Both of those should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I somehow failed to see that `topAgents ` was `dynamic` all this time.

Comment: I had a foreach loop with a dynamic object in a view. For this object I wanted to use a Linq where constraint, which of course didn't work. So I provided the dynamic object with a simple cast: ((IList<MyType>)ViewBag.MyObject).Where(p => p.MyProperty = property). This works very well!