# return dynamic object with all child nodes as Json in - error: cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched

Tags: c#, json, linq, dynamic

I have an object that I'm returning from a third party so I need it to be dynamic (see IEnumerable requirements below). I want to return the object as Json with all of its child nodes.

I have two questions

1. how can I do a  .Select on the dynamic object  (c.Nodes) (is this
   the way to go?)
2. How can I keep looping through the nodes until it's done.

This is the code I wrote so far but now `.Select( c =>...` is giving an error

> cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched...

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> requirements = _Requirements.GetRequirements();
  return Json(new
        {
            Requirements = requirements.Select(r => new
                {
                    r.Text,
                    r.Number,
                    nodes = r.nodes.Select(c => new
                        {
                            c.Text,
                            c.Number,
                            nodes = c.Nodes
                            //and overhere keep looping through the nodes until it's done
                        })
                 })
        });
```

Comment: why can't you do `return Json(new{ Requirements = requirements });`?

Comment: @GiladGreen each has a collection within it (up to 4 times). Does that mean I would have to do the .select on each node (4 times)?  Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this compile error is because your inner collection of `r.node` is a dynamic type and thus the extension methods can't be found for it.

Your case is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat). Instead what you should do is:

```
nodes = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)r.nodes)
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.Text,
            c.Number,
            nodes = c.Nodes
        //and overhere keep looping through the nodes until it's done
    })
```

*If you want to be sure that it won't get an exception when casting you can do 
`r.nodes is IEnumerable<dynamic> ? /*the select*/ : Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>`*

---

For second question, if I properly understood what you meant then you can write a recursive method that gets a `dynamic` and then checks if it has a `nodes` property which is an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and if so recursively calls itself foreach node in the `nodes`. Something along the general idea of:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> SomeName (dynamic input)
{
    var collection = input as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
    if (collection == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>();

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        /*recursive part*/
    }

    return collection;
}
```

*(Haven't tested - just quick concept writing)*

Comment: Thank you, that's working perfectly! How can I tell it to keep looping through the nodes?

Comment: @shw - see edit :) was just writing it. See code example