# How to exclude a single node id from a loop of CurrentPage.Children

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a template where I wish to display all of the CurrentPage's childnodes except a single node with Id = 1234.

My current code:

```
 @{
   foreach( var child in CurrentPage.Children.Take(6) ){

   Html.Partial("Archive/Post", new ViewDataDictionary {{ "item", (object)child }} )

        }
   }
```

So basically I'm trying to do something like:   CurrentPage.Children.Take(6).Where(Id != 1234)

Comment: "So basically I'm trying to do something like: CurrentPage.Children.Take(6).Where(Id != 1234)" - seems like a good option, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to do that:  "CS0103 the name 'Id' does not exist in the given context"

Comment: try `CurrentPage.Children.Take(6).Where(x => x.Id != 1234)`

Comment: So you finish only with 5 nodes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Where` method expects a predicate (usually provided as a lambda expression):

```
CurrentPage.Children.Take(6).Where(c => c.Id != 1234)
```

Following your comment, I came to the conclusion that either `CurrentPage` is `dynamic` or `Childern` is `dynamic`. Since [you can't use lambda expressions with `dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat), You can go the old fashion way and simply add the condition inside the loop:

```
@{
    foreach( var child in CurrentPage.Children.Take(6) )
    {
      if(child.Id != 1234)
          Html.Partial("Archive/Post", new ViewDataDictionary {{"item", (object)child}});
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing this I get:

Compiler Error Message: CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: Is `CurrentPage` declared a `dynamic`?

Comment: I tried:  dynamic myPage = CurrentPage;   Then referring to myPage.Children instead, but no effect. 

I'm pretty new to Umbraco so this is probably rather trivial :( 

I tried the above sollution first where i just check for the ID inside the foreach loop, but wanted to try to avoid this as It causes some issues later on in my template.

Comment: Is there really a need for `dynamic` here? I know nothing about Umbarco, but I do know that most of the time, using `dynamic` should be considered as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not sure myself neither. To make a clearer picture of what i'm trying to accomplish:

1. I have a content picker in this template which selects a single node as a "featured node".

2. In my template i wish to list all 6 first children of the current page EXCEPT the featured node (1234 in this case).

3. I have an additional list with hidden nodes below here which lists all remaining nodes, displayed with javascript on a button click "show more".

Comment: The background story is kinda irrelevant; that's not an uncommon scenario to want to filter out specific stuff from a collection. The problem here is probably that either `CurrentPage` or it's `Children` property is declared as `dynamic`. If you can use `var` instead of `dynamic`, it might solve your problem (that's why I've added the link to my answer)

Comment: This did the trick:
 IEnumerable<dynamic> pageChildren = CurrentPage.Children;  

Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Good to know for the future, when you don't want to use dynamics in Umbraco. You can use `Model.Content` instead of `CurrentPage`. This will return an object of type `IPublishedContent` and this way your intellisense in Visual Studio will help you a lot

Comment: Aha...thanks for the tip, @Mark .  Coming from PHP and mainly developing for WordPress, I got quite a learning curve ahead of me hehe :)