# Querying dynamic data

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

In short I know what the problem is, it's this ...

[Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat)

... I also know this is not possible by default.

My question (see below) here, is how can I make this possible (even if i have to dynamically call up the Roslyn compiler for example to generate a whole new concrete assembly)?

Is there any way i can make the following query possible in C#?

So lets assume I have the following sample data ...

```
var data = @"
{
    ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"",
    ""Items"":[
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":1, ""BuyerRef"":1, ""SupplierRef"":2, ""FaceValue"":1.34 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":1, ""BuyerRef"":1, ""SupplierRef"":2, ""FaceValue"":2.12 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":2, ""BuyerRef"":1, ""SupplierRef"":3, ""FaceValue"":100.0 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":3, ""BuyerRef"":1, ""SupplierRef"":2, ""FaceValue"":1.0 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":4, ""BuyerRef"":3, ""SupplierRef"":2, ""FaceValue"":1.0 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":5, ""BuyerRef"":4, ""SupplierRef"":1, ""FaceValue"":1.0 },
        { ""$type"":""System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject, System.Core"", ""Ref"":5, ""BuyerRef"":4, ""SupplierRef"":1, ""FaceValue"":1.0 }
    ],
    ""Companies"":[
        { ""CompanyId"":1, ""CompanyName"":""Sample Company 1"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":2, ""CompanyName"":""Sample company 2"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":3, ""CompanyName"":""ACME"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":4, ""CompanyName"":""HSBC Bank UK"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":5, ""CompanyName"":""Basic Buyer UK Ltd"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":6, ""CompanyName"":""Test Global US-CA"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":7, ""CompanyName"":""Test Global US-TX"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":8, ""CompanyName"":""Test Global US-NH"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":9, ""CompanyName"":""Test Global UK"" },
        { ""CompanyId"":10, ""CompanyName"":""Test Global FR"" }
    ]
}
";
```

Then I parse using Newtonsofts JsonConvert ...

```
object source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(data);
```

Now I want to do something like ...

```
var result = source.Items.Select(item => new
{
    Ref = item.Ref,
    FaceValue = item.FaceValue,
    BuyerId = item.BuyerRef,
    Buyer = Companies.Where(company => item.BuyerRef == company.CompanyId).Select(company => company).FirstOrDefault(),
    SupplierId = item.SupplierRef,
    Supplier = Companies.Where(company => item.SupplierRef == company.Ref).Select(company => company).FirstOrDefault()

})
.ToArray()
.GroupBy(i => new { i.Ref, i.Buyer, i.Supplier })
.Select(group => new
{
    Ref = group.Key.Ref,
    BuyerId = group.Key.Buyer.Ref,
    Buyer = group.Key.Buyer,
    SupplierId = group.Key.Supplier.Ref,
    Supplier = group.Key.Supplier,
    Lines = group.Select(i => new { Ref = i.Ref, FaceValue = i.FaceValue }).ToArray(),
    FaceValue = group.Sum(i => i.FaceValue)
})
.ToArray();
```

... The issue of course is that the data is completely dynamic and LINQ won't work with dynamic objects.

Assumptions that can be made ...

1. the data can be any data structure the above is just a sample to illustrate my problem.
2. The query is validated and checked and will definitely work against the data given when I want to perform this operation so i'm happy to avoid compiler level checks if that's possible.
3. My result is assumed to be just as dynamic and it's up to the consuming code to do what it needs to with that.

Is this possible in C# at all?

Comment: why call `.ToArray()` in the middle? That just takes up extra work and uses more memory.

Comment: The query code in question came from a string and was dynamically constructed ... a detail I left out as it wasn't relevant.

Comment: You are deserializing to an `ExpandoObject` which supports a `IDicictionary` interface for accessing properties (fields?). You should be able to create queries using `Expression` but your `Select`s would need to generate `ExpandoObject`s and not anonymous objects, which are classes normally created at compile time and not runtime, and are of limited usefulness when created at runtime - you can't pass them around either way. What would expect to do with the result of your dynamic query?

Comment: I think this task is easier if you have `ExpandoObject source = ...`  Then you can use the features of expando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've got it working with your sample data, but I had to change a fair amount of code:

First you need to tell the compiler to treat `source.Items` and `source.Companies` as `IEnumerable<dynamic>` values. That's easy enough just by extracting them to local variables and using an implicit conversion:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> items = source.Items;
IEnumerable<dynamic> companies = source.Companies;
```

Next, your queries are broken in various places because you're assuming that company entries have a `Ref` property - they don't, they only have `CompanyId`. This is where I have concerns about your assumption that "The query is validated and checked and will definitely work against the data given" - if that's not the case for the sample you've provided, how are you going to make sure it's the case in reality?

I've also converted your `...Where(...).Select(company => company).FirstOrDefault()` parts to just `.FirstOrDefault(...)` for simplicity. Additionally, for `Sum` to work you really need to make sure that every element has the same type - a cast is simplest for that.

Finally, I've removed the intermediate `ToArray` call, which does nothing particularly useful, and used projection initializers where the names of properties in anonymous types are the names of the properties you're extracting from. (You're already doing this in `GroupBy` - I'm just doing it more.)

That leaves the code as:

```
dynamic source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(data);
IEnumerable<dynamic> items = source.Items;
IEnumerable<dynamic> companies = source.Companies;
var result = items
    .Select(item => new
    {
        item.Ref,
        item.FaceValue,
        BuyerId = item.BuyerRef,
        Buyer = companies.FirstOrDefault(company => item.BuyerRef == company.CompanyId),
        SupplierId = item.SupplierRef,
        Supplier = companies.FirstOrDefault(company => item.SupplierRef == company.CompanyId)
    })
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Ref, i.Buyer, i.Supplier })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        group.Key.Ref,
        BuyerId = group.Key.Buyer.CompanyId,
        group.Key.Buyer,
        SupplierId = group.Key.Supplier.CompanyId,
        group.Key.Supplier,
        Lines = group.Select(i => new { i.Ref, i.FaceValue }).ToArray(),
        FaceValue = group.Sum(i => (decimal) i.FaceValue)
    })
    .ToArray();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

That at least prints out values - I don't know whether they're the ones you want or not, but hopefully they are...

Comment: Apologies for the broken code (copy paste errors) ... So that leaves me thinking ... what's the difference between a property on an ExpandoObject that contains an IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> and a local variable you extracted that contains the same cast to IEnumerable<dynamic> ... are they not from the compilers point of view the same thing?

Comment: @War: No, because the element types are different at compile time, leading to different delegate types for LINQ. Using an `IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>`, the type of the argument for `Select` would be `Func<ExpandoObject, ...>` - whereas using an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, the type of the argument for `Select` would be `Func<dynamic, ...>`. When you use an expression of compile-time type `ExpandoObject`, the compiler restricts you to members of that type, with no dynamic typing.