# Unable to Json.Serialize an array of objects inside a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

On a Razor script page of my ASP.NET Core 2.1 application I've used the following code to convert a property from a model's object array into a JavaScript text array:

```
var xyz = @Json.Serialize(Model.Select(x => x.PropName).ToArray());
```

However, I have a model where an object array is nested in the model and is not top level as it is in the previous example. When I attempt using the same code for the object array as follows:

```
var xyz = @Json.Serialize(Model.NestedObjArray.Select(x => x.PropName).ToArray());
```

I receive the following error: `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`.

I have attempted to for my expression to the likes this [article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/198/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operation) as follows:

```
var xyz = @Json.Serialize(Model.Po.Select(x => new Po { PoNumber = x.PoNumber })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@T3.0 ... I'd leave this as a comment, but I'm lacking 2 reputation points at the moment.

You need to assign your `Model` lambda expression to a non-dynamic variable before attempting serialization - even a 'var' assignment will work, it doesn't have to be an implicitly cast variable.  Then you should be able to make your assignment to your `xyz` variable.

See this similar question for more.
[Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27169521/2227967)

Comment: Although I'm not following what about the object array not being at the top level of the model would cause it to become "dynamic" and break but assigning it to `var` did the trick. `@{var xyz = (List<MyObj>)Model.MyObjList; }
    var abc = @Json.Serialize(xyz.Select(x => x.MyProp).ToArray());
}`

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that it has something to do with C# compile-time type checking vs. runtime type checking. Because the compiler doesn't know the type of object(s) you were serializing (at compile-time), it throws an error because there isn't any additional type inferencing in the language. Hope this helps