# C# Lambda expression using dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a copy of every entity that is a subclass of BaseEntity. I'm using the repository pattern to access the database, and my idea is to get a repository for each type, get the entities and add them back with different values. I have the following code in a .NET 6 application:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

BaseEntity.cs

```
public class BaseEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
}
```

ChildEntity.cs

```
public class ChildEntity : BaseEntity { ... }
```

MyController.cs

```
var childClasses = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseEntity))!.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)))
    .ToList();

foreach (var type in childClasses)
{
    Type repositoryType = typeof(IRepository<>);
    Type constructed = repositoryType.MakeGenericType(type);
    dynamic repository = _serviceProvider.GetService(constructed)!;
    var entities = repository.Set().Where(e => e.BaseId == 0).ToList();
    
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        entity.Id = 0;
        entity.BaseId = newBaseId;
        repository.Set().Add(entity);
    }

    await repository.GetContext().SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

But the `entities` line gives the error: `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`

I understand that this is a limitation of using `dynamic`, but is there any way around it? The only solution I came up with was enumerating the whole `Set()` and using a `foreach` + `if`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169521/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat)

Comment: Perhaps you could do a `.Cast<>()` between the `.Set()` and the `.Where()` ?

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. Also, what is `constructed` here?

Comment: Also, it's hard to help with an alternate solution here since it's not clear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: yeah... the real question is how you wana use `entities` :D (I assume that it would be kind of `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which is not very usefull in statically typed language)

Comment: @PhilipAtz And what would you cast it to though?

Comment: I have edited the question and code to be more clear.